# Получение объекта по координатам

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять, что необходимо сделать, чтобы вывести `GameObject` по координатам.
Есть код к примеру:

```
cam = MainCamera.main;
planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cam);
for (int i = 0; i < planes.Length; ++i) {
    Plane p = planes[i];
}
```

То есть выводит объекты, которые видит камера, как видим, тут используется `Plane` и у него можно получить:
`p.normal` (`Vector3`)
`p.distance` (`float`).

Но как мне потом зная `p.normal` координаты, вывести `GameObject`, который находится по данным координатам?

Comment: Хотя-бы документацию почитайте по `CalculateFrustumPlanes`. `Plane` это приметив, а не `GameObject`, а `normal` это не координаты. Да и вообще это не инструмент по поиску объектов.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, я это находил, ничем не помогло. Кстати, я не могу вешать каждому объекту скрипт. Это исключено в принципе, так как нет необходимости тулить скрипты там где можно и нельзя В моем случае, нужно только вывести список видимых камерой, иначе смысла нет от этих методов, я также мог и сделать бы дистанцию от объекта, к которому она привязана. Была еще мысля сделать триггер на камеру, но так и не понял, как это сделать и как колайдер ей сделать на всю камеру.... не врубаюсь, если поможете буду весьма признателен и благодарен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос:
На камеру кинул `BoxCollider`сделал нужный размер и повесил `OnTriggerEnter`.
Теперь когда камера попадает на объект, он выводится в `OnTriggerEnter`, а по `OnTriggerExit` - убираю с видимости.

Еще можно будет попробовать сделать, чтобы коллайдер менялся в зависимости от дистанции камеры или угла и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать методы [OnBecameInvisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) и [OnBecameVisible()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) они определяются в наследнике `MonoBehaviour` так же, как и методы `Start` или `Awake` и вызываются, когда объект начинает/перестаёт рендриться хотя бы одной камерой.

Соответственно вы можете использовать их для того, чтобы объект регистрировал себя в каком-нибудь списке, либо удалялся оттуда при вызовах соответствующих методов.

Comment: Пожалуйста, можете сделать пример, чтобы то, что видит камера вывелось списком в виде `GameObject` или `Transform`. То есть нужно выводить те объекты, которые видит камера. Я не понимаю, как мне эти методы помогут? даже не представляю, как их использовать...

Answer (score 0):

Вот то, о чем писал @M. Green, повесьте первый скрипт на камеру, а второй - на потенциально видимые объекты:

---

```
public class VisibleObjectsList : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<PotentiallyVisibleObject> list = new List<PotentiallyVisibleObject>();
}
```

---

```
public class PotentiallyVisibleObject : MonoBehaviour{
    private VisibleObjectsList list;

    void Start () {
        list = FindObjectOfType<VisibleObjectsList>();
    }

    void OnBecameInvisible(){
        list.list.Remove(this);
    }

    void OnBecameVisible(){
        list.list.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо Вы попробовали это запустить, чтобы поставить минус?

Comment: Я не ставил минус. Я хотел всего лишь получить объекты, которые в реальности видит камера, я был до последнего уверен, что такая возможность есть, получить объекты которые видит камера, из самой камеры, а не вешать всем объектам скрипт.

Comment: @FixiDens а я не лично к Вам обращался, а к минусатору =)

Comment: @FixiDens можно конечно и метематически определить попал ти boundingBox объекта во frustum, что Вы и пытались сделать, но юнька уже делает это под капотом, а скрипты можно навесить при старте автоматически

Comment: Получается что проблема зациклилась, раз все-таки `GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes` ? Получает объекты в поле видимости, то тогда как мне быть дальше? Может быть `Plane` как-то заменить можно?

Comment: GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes Возвращает плоскости, которые формируют пирамиду видимости, после этого Вам необходимо найnи то, что попало в объем, который образуется этими плоскостями

Comment: Уже интереснее вариант. но вот беда, откуда начать, тут опять -же как то нужно узнать эти плоскости и ко всему еще знать как это устроено. Я этого не могу пока понять, как вы хотите сделать, чтобы попадал объект? Была бы ценная информация, чтобы так можно было сделать, только откуда двигаться что нужно посчитать или начать хоть-бы как -то..

Comment: @FixiDens плоскость описывается точкой и вектором нормали, фрустум состоит из 6 плоскостей, Вам необходимо определить, с какой стороны от каждой плоскости нахрдится объект (или пересечение)

Comment: +сану, все-таки помогаете, правда я вообще не понимаю, ка кэто сделать, какие методы использовать, я ранее не сталкивался с этим и даже понятия не имею, что рассчитывать даже.

Comment: @FixiDens Вот эта функция`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`

Comment: Я бы сказал, что лучше пересчитать пересечения фрустума и AABB, чем вешать кучу скриптов.